# How to produce a tiled plot with one variable with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a tiled plot with ggplot2 with a single variable. The data looks like this:

```
fruit numbers
apples 6
peaches 2
grapes 10
cherries 2
... many more fruit
```

I can plot the same data as the x and as the y variables, I can use this code:

```
p <- qplot(fruit,fruit) + geom_tile(aes(fill=numbers))
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

The above plot is precisely what I would like to plot; however, I need the data arranged in a single horizontal 1-dimensional plot. How can I create a 1D horizontal titled plot with 1 variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p <- qplot(fruit," ") + geom_tile(aes(fill=numbers))
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to idea you could do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dataset (guessed the interpretation of the data).  The trick is to include a dummy y variable.

```
pacman_data <- data.frame(
    fruit = c("apples", "peaches", "grapes", "cherries"),
    numbers = c(6, 2, 10, 2),
    dummy = 1
)
```

Here's the plot.  You can use `geom_tile` or `geom_bar`, the only difference seems to be that `geom_bar` gives you a small gap between the tiles by default.

```
p_base <- ggplot(pacman_data, aes(fruit, dummy, fill = numbers)) +
    ylab("") +
    opts(axis.text.y = theme_blank())
p_base + geom_tile()
p_base + geom_bar()
```